# Updating a column using between

Tags: sql-server, ssms, between

The issue is updating the `Class` column. The below table is a short snippet of the structure. The `Class` column is currently empty and needs updating based on values in the membership column. For example, membership of 12 would be class 3.

```
Membership    Class
  0 to 4        1
  5 to 9        2
 10 to 19       3
```

Would the following code be sufficient:

```
Update dbo.tablename 
set class = 1 
where 'membership' between 0 and 4
```

Comment: Yeap that should do it!

Comment: FYI, for database questions where SQL is the only programming language involved, see the sister site: [*dba.StackExchange.com*](http://dba.StackExchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take out quotes around your column name :

```
Update dbo.tablename set class=1 where membership between 0 and 4
```

Then run the same for different membership ranges.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server (or one of several other databases), you shouldn't bother with a `class` column.  Instead, use a computed column:

```
alter dbo.tablename add class as
    (case when membership between 0 and 4 then 1
          when membership between 5 and 9 then 2
          when membership between 10 and 19 then 3
     end);
```

The value is calculated when you refer to the column, so it is always up-to-date.